# Ubuntu forgets custom DNS server after a while

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns

I am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I have configured the IPv4 DNS to manual resolution always (Automatic = Off) and added 192.168.0.5 as my DNS server.

So for a while it all works, pinging some servers that I've configured on my dns server correctly resolve.

```
ping server.lan
```

.... resolves server.lan IP

But after a while it doesn't:

```
dig server.lan

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1-Ubuntu <<>> server.lan
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 36327
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;server.lan.            IN  A

;; Query time: 16 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Wed May 02 21:37:33 BST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 39
```

After rebooting, it works ok for a while.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: did you find any fixes? I have to run `sudo netplan apply` every day to remind ubuntu about my dns servers.

Comment: Me too. I even thought of creating a cron job to hourly run `netplan apply`, but this really can't be a good solution, because there are many Ubuntu instances I have to do this on. If you or anybody else has a solution on this, please tell us.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are editing where, BUT In Ubuntu 17.10 they changed to netplan to manage networks.

for desktop it is now netplan/networkmanager
for server (headerless) it is now netplan/networkd

So basically anything you have edited in the past doesn't really work anymore. To make life more confusing it is all still there, and editing it can just add further layers of problem (that's experience talking). Once I just started working with only the netplan stuff, everything started to work again.

As far as I understand you now edit gui from within the gui (I don't use the gui), if you google ubuntu 18.04 static ip netplan networkd you will probably find what you are looking for. I have only just discovered most of this, and I am still not 100% sure how it all works, which is why I have not told you how I setup my network stuff. Bad advise only makes things worse.

My key info was found here: https://websiteforstudents.com/configure-static-ip-addresses-on-ubuntu-18-04-beta/

Hope this helps.